# Is it possible to compute descriptor at a given position which may or may not be qualified as a keypoint?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I want to analyze the similarity of two images.
A conventional way for this is

1. Detect features(keypoints) for both images.
2. Compute descriptors for every keypoints.
3. Compute a match using these two sets of descriptors.

However in my case I have already had the matched point sets from two images.
So I think I can directly proceed to the second step for descriptor computation.
Is it reasonable and possible?

Comment: if you have matched points, why do you want to compute the descriptors at all? do you want to verify the matches? You can compute a descriptor at any point you want, but often the first step in descriptor computation is to compute the `orientation` of the keypoint. Depending on the method and the "quality" of the keypoint, this orientation extraction might or might not be possible robustly.

Comment: @Micka "why do you want to compute the descriptors at all?" My goal was to provide a "similarity" value for a pair of images. This could be a usual job by using feature matching. But some of our inputs may not have much significant  gradient difference. So the results of these inputs are not good enough. I noticed that I already have the matched points(The images are rendered by a textured 3D mesh. The matched point is the mesh vertices actually). I think I can make use of this, then I want to try compute descriptors based on matched points.

Comment: You can warp one of the images and compute any similarity value (e.g. MSSIM) on the registrated images.

Answer (score 0):

yes, its possible to compute descriptors for any point, be it a keypoint or not. After all, a descriptor is just a representation of intensities in a patch. For computing similarity, you could use bag of words.

A better way to compute image similarity is to compare mid level deep features, which can be easily computed using CAFFE caffe.berkeleyvision.org.